# Не могу понять как правильно писать Xpath функции

Tags: c#, htmlagilitypack

Мне нужно запарсить сайт с помощью  `HtmlAgilityPack`
На сайте есть ссылки и у всех такой класс: `class="css-ytumd6 e1j8zk4s1"`
Я не могу разобраться как правильно писать Xpath для них(

Поможете?)

Comment: нужен просто селектор для данного класса?

Comment: Да, я должен провести поиск по этому классу и не могу понять как правильно написать его, а то компилятор ругает)

Comment: var x = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("[class='css - ytumd6 e1j8zk4s1')]").Elements("a").ToList();

Comment: Что может быть не правильно?

Comment: Попробуйте расширение для хрома ChroPath, он помогает отловить Xpath выражение для вашего искомого элемента, очень удобно.

Comment: `var x = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".css-ytumd6.e1j8zk4s1").Elements("a").ToList();` так попробуйте

Comment: `SelectNodes("//a[@class='css-ytumd6 e1j8zk4s1']")`